# What is the typical method for securely exposing some data on a public website that is taken from internal databases?

Tags: asp.net, intranet

I have a few internal databases and intranet site on a server that's totally inaccessible from the outside world.  And I have an external website on a completely off-network server.

There is a handful of data on the internal databases that I want available on the public website, but the internal databases also contain sensitive data that I want to away from the public site.

How is this typically handled?  I am not entirely sure what to search for.  Right now, I manually dump this needed data to an XML file used by the website, but I feel like there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options that I can think of, and most likely more than what I'm about to list... not much of a network guy.

- Set up a firewall rule that allows the port requests from the external server's IP address to the internal database server.
- Set up a external facing service that only exposes the data you wish to share.  You can have authentication/authorization set up on this service to only allow the users you wish to access the data to have access.  Additionally, you could set up the service to only allow calls from the external web site's IP address similar to the above solution.

Either way I think you're going to have to get a network guy involved.